# How to use show to print character without single quotes?

Tags: haskell

I'm defining an instance of the Show typeclass for a custom data type where in the single lettered character name is returned but it returns so with quotes.

More generally,

`show 'a'` returns as `"'a'"` in the console.

how do I return it as `"a"` (without the single quotes) but while still using show?
Edit: Figured it out right after I posted the question. All I had to do was treat the char as a singleton list of char.
`show [a]` returns what I want

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Text-Show.html - "The result of show is a syntactically correct Haskell expression.." - wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with [**`putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn) to print the *content* of the string to the output channel:

```
putStrLn "a"
```

or if you work with a single character, you can use:

```
putStrLn ['a']
```