# Creating a full name from initials and surname haskell

Tags: haskell, types

As input:
`initials = "HB"`, `surname = "Curry"`
and output should be the full name: `H. B. Curry` with a `.`  interspersed between the initials and the surname

I had:
`intersperse '.' initials ++ "." ++ surname`
which gives `H.B.Curry` (incorrect because there's no space)

to intersperse a string `". "` instead of the char `'.'` I needed the second argument to be a list of strings.

So I tried `map show initials` expecting `["H", "B"]` but got `["'H'", "'B'"]`

which meant `intercalate ". " $ map show initials` gave `'H'. 'B'` instead of `H. B` like I wanted.

This thread [How to use show to print character without single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341841/how-to-use-show-to-print-character-without-single-quotes) uses the `IO ()` which I don't want to use, as I'm just returning the full name not printing to console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`intercalate` is, in some sense, the wrong function to use. You want to *append* `". "` to each initial (or more precisely, for each initial, *prepend* `". "` with an initial), not just separate initials with `". "`.

```
> concatMap (: ". ") initials ++ surname
"H. B. Curry"
```

`concatMap` applies the given function to each character of the initials, then joins them into a single string. To this string, you append the surname.

---

Breaking `concatMap` down into its individual steps,

```
> map (: ". ") initials
["H. ","B. "]
> concat (map (: ". ") initials)
"H. B. "
> (concat . map (: ". ")) initials
"H. B. "
```

Because `concatMap f = concat . map f`,

```
> concatMap (: ". ") initials
"H. B. "
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is converting a `Char` to a `String`. Even though `show` has a correct type (`Char -> String`), it converts in a different way. For example, `show 'a'` is `"'a'"`, not `"a"`.

So you need a function to convert `'a'` to `"a"` instead. Since a `String` is a list of `Char`, you can build a `String` from `Char` by a function like this.

```
charToString :: Char -> String
charToString c = [c]
```

With it, `intercalate ". " $ map charToString initials` gives you `"H. B"`.

Note that `charToString` is equivalent to `(:[])`, so you can also write it as `intercalate "." $ map (:[]) initials`.

Comment: If you're listing shorter equivalents, `charToString = pure` is also correct.